# ¿Es posible modificar este prototipo?

Tags: javascript, html5, canvas, prototipos

Es posible hacer esto sin que "this" sea ¿undefined?:

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    ctx.prototype.drawRectGrid = (color = "#fff",traceLen,spaceLen)=>{
        console.log(this);//Aquí
    }

    ctx.drawRectGrid();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Es que necesito el this para utilizar los metodos de ctx dentro de la función de prototype (Donde esta el comentario), pero si intento usar este código no me deja modificar el objeto ctx (dice que es undefined), y cuando hago lo mismo pero reemplazando prototype por `__proto__`, me muestra en la consola que this, es undefined. es decir no me muestra la referencia a ctx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes dos fallos:

- Estás intentando añadir la función a la instancia y no a la clase. Esto en sí no es incorrecto, pero te sobraría el `.prototype`.
- Una función *flecha* tiene el contexto en el que fue creada, por lo que siempre será `window`.

Por tanto, podrías solucionarlo así:

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    
    ctx.drawRectGrid = function (color = "#fff",traceLen,spaceLen) {
        console.log(this);//Aquí
    };
    
    ctx.drawRectGrid();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

Principal error: `ctx` es solo una instancia del `CanvasRenderingContext2D`. En lugar de `ctx.prototype.drawRectGrid = (...` haz esto: `CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.drawRectGrid = (`

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

//ctx.prototype.drawRectGrid = (... 
// ctx es solo una instáncia del CanvasRenderingContext2D. Haz esto:
CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.drawRectGrid = (color = "#fff",traceLen,spaceLen)=>{
    //console.log(this); esto devuelve el objeto "window".
    // Pero esto funciona pero no es lo que tu quieres
     console.log("this");

}

ctx.drawRectGrid("red",30,30);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Espero que sea útil

Comment: ¡La verdad ambos comentarios fueron de mucha ayuda!, el primero, el de Pablo Lozano ya que ahora se que las funciones flecha tienen el contexto del objeto que los creo, y el segundo, enxaneta, que justo da con el nombre del objeto que necesito, es decir en contexto 2d propio del canvas, (CanvasRenderingContext2D), al cual es el objeto en especifico que le quiero agregar tal función, así que mezclare ambas soluciones para poder usar el contexto this que necesitaba usar, sin embargo... como ambas soluciónes son utiles, no se a quien dar la pregunta como resuelta...